# How do I setup local notification repeated each 7, 14, 28 days from specific day

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I need to push local notification each 7, 14, 28 days.
I had successfully setup to push weekly (7 days)
I am not fully understand how DateComponents works.
IE: I need to repeat notification each minute, I do `Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: fireDate)` How does it work with repeated 14 days, 28 days.

```
// datetime is timestamp which I can choose: ie: May 02, 2029

let fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(truncating: datetime) / 1000)
        let fireDateComps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: fireDate)

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = note
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.categoryIdentifier = "timer.category"

        var triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: fireDate)
        var repeats = false
        switch (recurring) {
        case "weekly":
            triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([ .weekday , .hour , .minute , .second], from: fireDate)
            repeats = true
            print("reminder repeat weekly")
        case "every_two_weeks":
            print("triggerDate 1 \(fireDate)")
            let aaa = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 14, to: fireDate)
            print("triggerDate 2 \(aaa)")
            triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: aaa!)
            print("triggerDate 3 \(triggerDate)")
            repeats = true
            print("reminder repeat every_two_weeks")
        case "every_four_weeks":
            triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([ .month , .hour , .minute , .second], from: fireDate)
            repeats = true
            print("reminder repeat every_four_weeks")
        default:
            triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([ .year, .month, .day , .hour , .minute , .second], from: fireDate)
            repeats = false
            print("No recurring")
        }
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: repeats)
        print("trigger \(trigger), firstRepeatingDate \(triggerDate)")
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id,
                                            content: content, trigger: trigger)
        self.center.add(request) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                Log.nonFatal("Save notification failed \(String(describing: error))")
                reject("reminder", "Save reminder notification failed", error)
            }
            print("Saved recurring notification")
            resolve(true)
        }
```

Comment: You need to store last fire date in local db e.g if you want to fire notification every 14 days then just add 14 days in last fire date. so its work fine I think

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I have used these apis, but based on the documentation here is a quick example for a couple of them (the one you use and the one I am proposing):

```
// UNCalendarNotificationTrigger (Trigger at specific date & time)
// This example fires a notification every day at 08:30

var date    = DateComponents()
date.hour   = 8
date.minute = 30 
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)

/* I guess date.day = 1 would fire at the 1st day of each month
   whereas date.weekOfMonth = 2 would fire at the second week of each month etc 
*/
```

What you may want instead is to fire periodically:

```
// UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger (Trigger after an amount of time has elapsed)
// This example fires a notification every 14 days (14d * 24h * 60m * 60s)

let days = 14
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(days * 24 * 60 * 60), repeats: true)
```

Comment: Actually I need both of them. UNCalendarNotificationTrigger and UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger to recurring the notification.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved the question.

```
func calendarAddNotification(id: String, title: String, datetime: NSNumber, note: String, recurring: String) {

let fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(truncating: datetime) / 1000)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = note
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    content.categoryIdentifier = "timer.category"

    // setup normal notification
    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: fireDate)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)
    self.center.add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            Log.nonFatal("Save notification failed \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            print("Saved notification")
        }
    }
    // non-recurring notification, return
    if (!["weekly", "every_two_weeks", "every_four_weeks"].contains(recurring)) {
        print("No recurring notification")
        return
    }

    // recurring notification
    var interval = 0
    switch (recurring) {
    case "weekly":
        interval = 7
        print("reminder repeat weekly")
    case "every_two_weeks":
        interval = 14
        print("reminder repeat every_two_weeks")
    case "every_four_weeks":
        interval = 28
        print("reminder repeat every_four_weeks")
    default:
        print("No recurring")
    }
    // add interval day to the fireDate
    let recurringDateComponent = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: interval, to: fireDate)
    let recurringTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: recurringDateComponent!.timeIntervalSinceNow, repeats: true)
    let recurringRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "recurring_" + id,
                                        content: content, trigger: recurringTrigger)
    self.center.add(recurringRequest) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            Log.nonFatal("Save recurring notification failed \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            print("Saved recurring notification")
        }
    }
}
```